# "undefined" is appearing for first time during validation on JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, jsp

I am validating user input where it should accept only 6 digits or OB followed by 8 digits only.

It works very fine for digits but when I enter any alphabet (other than O) for first time it shows "undefined" in the input text box. How to overcome this? I have initialize all variables and tried changing regular expression(/[OB0-9]*/) also but nothing is working.

Here is my jsp code with RegEx:

```
<input type="text" value="<c:out value='${bookingPathView.extraAANumber}'/>" name="businessExtrAA" id="enterPassengerDetailsForm.businessExtrAA" size="17" maxlength="10" pattern="[OB0-9]*" class="forceWidth-phone forceWidth6" />
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
var keepBusinessExtraMaxLength = function () {
        var input = [];
        jQuery("#enterPassengerDetailsForm\\.businessExtrAA").each(function(i) {
            input[i]=this.defaultValue;
            jQuery(this).data("idx",i);
        });
        jQuery("#enterPassengerDetailsForm\\.businessExtrAA").on("keyup", function (e) {
            var field = jQuery(this);
             var val=this.value;
              var maxLength=isNaN(jQuery(field).val()) ? Number(jQuery(field).attr("maxlength")) : 6;
              var thisIndex=jQuery(field).data("idx");
            if (this.validity && this.validity.badInput || jQuery(field).is(":invalid") ) {
                this.value = input[jQuery(thisIndex)];
                return;
            }     
            if (val.length > maxLength) {
                val=val.slice(0, maxLength);
                jQuery(field).val(val);
            }

            input[jQuery(thisIndex)]=val;
        });        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex seems to be matching only the characters , `O`, `B` and other numbers...
To make it match

> 6 digits or OB followed by 8 digits only

You can use this regex: `^(?:[0-9]{6}|OB[0-9]{8})$`

Demonstration: http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=96586

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Mateus, but this is not working for me. As I am checking one character/number at a time, "OB[0-9]" is failing. I tried ([0-9]*)|(^O[B0-9]*) but this is also giving same error "undefined"